# Need to understand answer of algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am trying to solve above Longest Monotonically Increasing Subsequence problem using javascript. In order to do that, I need to know about Longest Monotonically Subsequence. Current I am following [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence#Example) article. The thing I am not understanding this example is that the longest increasing subsequence is given as `0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15` from `0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15, …` list. The question is **Why the answer does not have 3 in between 2 and 6, and 8 between 6 and 9 etc? How does that answer come from that list?**

Comment: That is because this does not happen in the original array either.

Comment: Depends the definition of subsequence.

Comment: @Anonymous could you please give a bit detail answer with example?

Comment: @user1990169 Could you elaborate your comment please or may be turn it into an answer with more detail?

Comment: @2619 Why do you think 3 should be included?

Comment: @user1990169 because it is in the increasing sequence i.e. 3 comes after 2 not 6. I mean order.

Answer (score 1):

Ist of all , consider the name "Longest Monotonically Increasing Subsequence" . So , from the given array you need to figure out the largest sequence where the numbers should be appeared in a strictly increasing fashion. There can be **many sequence**, where the sub array can be strictly increasing but you need to find the **largest** sub-Array.

So. lets debug this array. a[] = {0, 8, 4, 12, 2, 10, 6, 14, 1, 9, 5, 13, 3, 11, 7, 15}

In here the some monotonously increasing sub-arrays are :

{0,8,12,14,15} Length = 5

{0,4,12,14,15} Length = 5

{0,1,9,13,15} Length = 5 and so on.

But if you calculate like this , you can find the largest sub-array will be :

**{0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15}** , Length = 6, so this is the answer.

Every single little time you pick any number , the next number should be large than the previous one and must be present in the array. say  {0, 2, 6, 9, 13, 15} this list, when you pick **9** , then the next number should be larger than 9. the immediate sequence shows **13>9**, so you can pick **13**. You can also pick 11. But that will create another branch of sub-array. Like :
**{0, 2, 6, 9, 11, 15}** which is another solution.

Hope this explanation will help you to understand the LIS (Longest Increasing Subsequence).Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the title of your question says: Longest increasing CONTIGUOUS subsequence which is a slight variation of the original problem of LIS in which the result need not have contiguous values from original array as pointed out in above examples. Follow this link for a decent explanation on LIS algorithm which has O(n^2) solution and it can be optimized to have a O(nlogn) solution:
http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Longest_Increasing_Subsequence

for the contiguous variant of LIS, here is a decent solution:
http://worldofbrock.blogspot.com/2009/10/how-to-find-longest-continuous.html

Comment: your second link does not return array. would be nice if you could post a sample answer here with code that returns array.